# How replicate the value of Y Axis on both sides of the axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need only replicate the value of Y axes on both sides os the axis. Note that my chart DOES NOT have multiple axes.

Look the example: `[http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/]`

I know it's something simple, but I could not find the solution.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You still need to specify multiple axes, and then you can use the 'linkedTo' and 'opposite' properties:

```
 yAxis: [{
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },{
                linkedTo:0,
                opposite:true
            }],
```

.

**Edit for clarification based on comment below:**

Highstock, at the time of this writing, sets the `opposite` property as `true` for the `yAxis` by default.

However, Highstock is not a "version of Highcharts". 
Highstock is its own product, originating from and related to Highcharts.

All versions of Highcharts currently set `opposite` to `false` both axes by default - `yAxis` will be on the left, and `xAxis` will be on the bottom.

Comment: Depending on the version of Highcharts you're using, `Axis.opposite` may default to `true`, so you may want the second axis to have `opposite` set to `false` instead.

Comment: In what version is opposite for either axis set to true by default? That would be an odd default setting...

Comment: Fraxtil is right. In HighStocks, the default side is right(which is left in HghCharts), and setting opposite = false in HighStocks results in Y-Axis on the opposite side

Comment: As a note: if your current yAxis has a specific type defined (e.g. `type: "datetime"`, you'll need to specify that on the linked axis to avoid Highcharts Error 11.